# I lost some of my work while refactoring a storyboard on XCode? What can I do?

Tags: swift, storyboard, interface-builder, ios9, xcode7

I have read the First Book from appcoda **"Beginning programming with Swift"**

One feature that I learned in said book and that I really liked while working with storyboards is the ability to refactor some storyboards when the amount of storyboards becomes too large, so at first I was doing it successfully, no problem whatsoever.

I began dividing my storyboards into smaller chunks like so

[image]

## OH THE HORROR

### then this happened

As soon as I pressed "refactor to storyboards" it didn't prompt me for a name as it did before but instead it renamed the new storyboard reference to "Main copy.storyboard"

[image]

## Can I recover the storyboard that I lost?

When that happened, the old storyboard dissapeared and an exact copy of the main.storyboard appeared

CTROL-Z Did not work as I tried that immediately and I haven't versioned for the past 2 days or so (I know, that was really stupid)

If I can not recover the storyboard, can someone tell me why did this happen? I don't want to do this again

Btw, I am running the last version of XCode 7.2.1

Comment: I am using Git for this project but still some work would be lost if I go back, but most importantly I would like to know why this happened as I am fairly new to XCode and iOS programming

Comment: If the copy is the same as main, delete main and rename the copy.

Comment: please select you storyboard and click on the "show the version editor" button on top right 3rd button on the xcode . and the find out what changes were done in which branch .

Comment: Use the Finder to look in your project folder and in the Trash. Maybe you'll find the lost file.

Comment: @robmayoff thank you so much. By looking in the trash I was able to find the lost storyboard. However, I am now staying away from refactoring storyboards, it seems like it's buggy, I don't know if it is my project but I tried doing it again and the same thing is happening

Comment: FWIW I saw this same behavior (not asking to name the refactored storyboard) when I tried refactoring a storyboard I had selected from the "Base.lproj" folder (managed by Xcode) by mistake.  Selecting the file in my own folder worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode may have put the lost storyboard in the Trash. Use the Finder to check. The Trash is the wastebasket-looking thing at the right or bottom end of the Dock.

If the lost file is in the Trash, you may be able to right-click it and choose “Put Back” to send it back into your project folder. You may also need to add it back to your project in Xcode using File > Add Files to “*MyProject*”.

Answer (score 0):

I got in to the same problem. If you accidentally replaced the original storyboard with new one while refactoring, you can find the old one in project folder with a name ending with "~" symbol.

[image]

Hope you can restore it from there.